# How to merge 2 schemas in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have 2 different databases that I would like to merge into one or simply to combine both databases to be used as one model.

Comment: You need to be a little mode specific. Are these 2 versions of the same database with the same table names? Or just 2 totally different databases you now want to make into one?

Comment: @Riggs, There are 2 Different Database from Different Source and all have the different table's name but both have a table with the same field name like: username, password. And I want to use the other Database to enable the user to use the same information to login.

Comment: The word "model" totally irritates me as this refers to something completely different (modeling in MySQL Workbench). At least I would have given you a completely different answer (e.g. how to merge two models). But others have read between the lines and gave you what you really meant.

Comment: @MikeLischke I'm Still looking for the best answer! but others have given me some option to try and to keep me busy! Please feel free to shoot me something that you have inside you mind. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the tables in both databases are having same schema, you can just use `UNION` to connect both databases' elements.

EX:

```
SELECT column
 FROM `database1`.`tableX`
  WHERE column_name="abc"
UNION
SELECT column
 FROM `database2`.`tableY`
  WHERE column_name="abc"
```

Comment: @adrach hota That is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: what if there are repeated content?

Answer (score 5):

**Database**->**Migration Wizard**.

Select your **Source** and **Target** database.

In **Schema Selection** select **Only one schema**, and the table schemas you want to merge

Much more and better detailed [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-overview-steps.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply take dumps of them both and upload them to the same database. Loading one will not delete the other.On the CLI:

```
create database new_database

mysqldump old_db_1 > old_db_1.sql
mysqldump old_db_2 > old_db_2.sql

mysql -u<username> -p<password> new_database < old_db_1.sql
mysql -u<username> -p<password> new_database < old_db_2.sql
```

Comment: I hope its as simple as that, but what if he wants to merge 2 tables into one. This wont work

Comment: Im not even sure its possible if you wanted to merge two tables into one as you'd lose your unique IDs and all their references would be useless.

Comment: @JackalopeZero you are right. That's why I need to use the database separately but in one query.

Comment: Then adarsh hota's answer is what you're looking for

Comment: @JacklopeZero Yes! Adarsh is right. Thank you too for your time